# Regular expression to check Not Null values and empty strings

Tags: regex

What would be the regular expression to check a string value is "`Not null and not empty"` in java?
i tried like this `"/^$|\s+/"`, but seems not working.

Comment: Is this the question, really?

Comment: So you consider `" "` to be "empty"?

Comment: The regex `/^$|\s+/` equates to 'empty string OR any string containing at least one whitespace character'

Comment: Also, why the slashes? Java isn't PHP, it doesn't have regex delimiters (but it does require backslashes to be escaped)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering this: your string can not contain "null" as string:

```
String.valueOf(input).matches("^null|$");
```

Otherwise check `input != null` and remove `null|` from the regex.

Comment: Anchors are unnecessary with the `.matches()` method.

Answer (score 5):

```
".*\\S+.*"
```

This means there is at least one non-whitespace character in the string.  But you should watch out—if you call the string as an implicit parameter and it's null, you'll see a NullPointerException.  Thus, it's probably better to check for null using conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check for not-null using a regular expression, because that regex is run against the String.

To check the String isn't empty you can just use `!myString.isEmpty()`

so `if(myString != null && !myString.isEmpty())`

Of course, in Groovy it would just be `if(myString)` ;)